# Splash screen with androidx.core:core-splashscreen not working

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am trying to use this library `androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01`
but couldnt figure out how is it working. I want to display image at the center and at the bottom, but it`s likely there is no method for displaying image aside from background image, or they are not working.

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.SSSplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">
            @drawable/ic_baseline_build_24
        </item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MySplashScreen</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69826671/3022177